# How to detect if a Set of Sets contains another Set?

Tags: java, set, equals

It is weird:
A is a Set and B is a Set of Sets:

```
Set <String> A=new HashSet<String>();
Set <Set<String>> B=new HashSet<Set<String>>();
```

I added things to them and the output of

```
System.out.println(A)
```

is:

```
[evacuated, leave, prepc_behind]
```

and the output of

```
System.out.println(B)
```

is:

```
[[leave,  to, aux], [auxpass,  were, forced], [leave,  evacuated, prepc_behind]]
```

as it can be seen, third element of set B equals to set A. So hypothetically

```
if(B.contains(A)){...}
```

should return true, but apparently it does not. What is the problem?

More Details:

```
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*?)\\((.*?)\\-\\d+,(.*?)\\-\\d+\\).*");
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        Set <String> tp = new HashSet<String>();
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(list.get(i).toString());
        if (m.find()) {
            tp.add(m.group(1).toLowerCase());
            tp.add(m.group(2).toLowerCase());
            tp.add(m.group(3).toLowerCase());
        }
        B.add(tp);
    }
    Set <String> A=new HashSet<String>();
    A.add("leave");
    A.add("evacuated");
    A.add("prepc_behind");
    System.out.println(A);
    if(B.contains(A)){
    System.out.println("B contains A");
}
```

Comment: How are you adding elements? Because `B.contains(A)` returns true for me.

Comment: Works as intended (i.e., returns true) for me too.

Comment: I have a for loop which keeps adding sets to B using: B.add(tp); tp is a set.

Comment: Can you post your loop above?

Comment: Not sure if this is a formatting error or not, but I see a space before "evacuated" in the second output but not the first. If "evacuated" is on one set and " evacuated" is in the other, you'd see the behavior described.

Comment: @Marcus : is there extra whitespace in any of the Strings in set B or is that just the formatting?

Comment: Can you please post all of your code so that we can have a look how it works?

Comment: There's interestingly an extra space in front of the second element in EACH of the sets stored in B.

Comment: Don't use capitals for variable names. i.e. "A" should be "a".

Comment: @ William Brendel: You are right! that extra space is the problem. thanks guys!

Comment: @ drekka: I changed the name here. A stands for clause, B stands for dependency.

Comment: According to a quick read of the API even if set A is a different set but with the same values, they should be equal. However, it would appear here that there is an extra whitespace character then the sets would be different.

Answer (score 3):

The basic idea (`setA.contains(setB) == true`) seems to work fine:

```
    Set<String>      set1 = new HashSet<String>();
    Set<Set<String>> set2 = new HashSet<Set<String>>();
    Set<String>      tmpSet;

    set1.add("one");
    set1.add("three");
    set1.add("two");

    tmpSet = new HashSet<String>();
    tmpSet.add("1");
    tmpSet.add("2");
    tmpSet.add("3");
    set2.add(tmpSet);

    tmpSet = new HashSet<String>();
    tmpSet.add("one");
    tmpSet.add("two");
    tmpSet.add("three");
    set2.add(tmpSet);

    System.out.println(set2.contains(set1)); // true
```

I would hazard a guess that you are capturing more in your regular expression then you would like.
Try converting both the match from the regex and the test string to `byte[]` and checking them against each other.

Answer (score -1):

Set.contains(other) return true if an element belongs to the set is equals to other.

And Set  has override equals() and hash().Set.equals() will return true if both sets has the same elements.

So,if A2 belongs to B,and A2 has the same elements as A,B.contains(A) will return true;